# How can i stop the grub config from being changed during a clean ubuntu install to another partition

Tags: installation, grub2

Every time i install ubuntu to another partition on my computer my grub settings are changed. Eg getting the `frequency out of range error` and having to uncomment  `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` every install.

Does the importing  accounts option  on installation also import the current GRUB settings  from the last OS ?

How can i stop the grub configuration  being changed when doing a clean install on another hard drive  partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply change it in the file `/etc/default/grub`; change `GRUB_GFXMODE=HHHxVVV` to 640x480.

If you want to know more about grub, you can read the manual at [this URL](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)

Comment: Hi Marty,i know how to fix the issues in `/etc/default/grub` .I wanted to know how to stop the ubuntu installation,on a secondary partition, overriding changes already made to the `/etc/default/grub` with previous OS.

Comment: You can do most things using the various configuration files, but it's possible to manually maintain grub.cfg, I think.  One thing you can do is set `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in /etc/default/grub to keep it from changing existing entries. There may be a way to prevent the entire process of generating the grub.cfg, but I never tried.  Or, you could go back to the original grub, I suppose.